# Android: App Not Showing in Phone after Debugging

Tags: android

whenever I used to debug/run my app via Android Studio, it showed up in my phone even after I disconnected the USB cable from my computer. But now the app doesn't show in any of the devices after disconnection. I know this may be a possible duplicate or may sound silly but I couldn't find the right keywords to search for my problem since I'm quite new to Android. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does you compile successful? ( without error )

Comment: Yeah, it does without any errors.

Comment: Which device are you using for testing?

Comment: Xiaomi Redmi 1S and YU Yureka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it was extremely foolish of me not to specify the launcher activity in Android manifest.